# SQL server, concat nvarchar when some are null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Probably a question of null values...

I would like to do just like in C# :

```
string s3 = s2 + ' ' + s1;
```

witch could be read like :

```
'hello world' = 'hello' + ' ' + 'world
```

But in SQL, some of my NVARCHAR(1) are null, so it sometimes look like :

```
null = 'hello + ' ' + null
```

And in this case i would rather have :

```
'hello ' = 'hello' + ' ' + null
```

I don't see, is there a simple way to do that ?

Comment: ISNULL(possibleNullVal, '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(S2, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(S1, '')
```

Or:

```
SELECT ISNULL(S2, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(S1, '')
```

Comment: COALESCE() is really doing it, i wonder what are these letters for though... can't make any sense out of them

Comment: Letters?  I'm not sure what you're referencing

Comment: just saw COALESCE is an english word ! haha, never heard it before

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IIF() function or else CASE Statement

SELECT IIF(s2 IS NULL, '', s2) + ' ' + IIF(s1 IS NULL, '', s1)